# GROUPING SETS returning unexpected results with calculated expression

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, group-by

Here we have two similar queries using `grouping sets`
where the `SELECT` clause contains some expressions calculated in aggregation:

```
SELECT RN10, RN10 / 10, COUNT(*) FROM 
(
       SELECT RN, RN/10 AS RN10, RN/100 AS RN100 FROM 
       (
               SELECT RN = -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0) 
               FROM master..spt_values
       ) A
) B
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((RN10), (RN10 / 10), ())
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

it's plan is here: [first query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ2Y7-iqI)

and

```
SELECT RN10, SUBSTRING(RN,3,99), COUNT(*) FROM 
(
       SELECT RN, SUBSTRING(RN,2,99) AS RN10 FROM 
       (
               SELECT RN = CAST(-1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0) AS VARCHAR(99)) 
               FROM master..spt_values
       ) A
) B
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((RN10), (SUBSTRING(RN,3,99)), ())
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

the corresponding plan is here: [second query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HymWVZo9L)

Both the queries first calculate some expression for aggregation, `RN10 / 10` in the first case and `SUBSTRING(RN,3,99)` in the second, then the same expression is used in the `SELECT` clause but as the first plan shows it's re-calculated in the first query and it's not in the second.

As the result we have `NULL`s in the first result set that is quite unexpectedly:

[image: results]

Can someone explain why the first query makes the calculation 2 times (one in aggregation and one more time in the final `select`) while the second makes it one time only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to use a simpler example where it is clear to see what the expected results are.

```
CREATE TABLE Queen
(
   FirstName        VARCHAR(7),
   Surname          VARCHAR(7)
); 

INSERT INTO Queen
    (FirstName, Surname)
VALUES
    ('Brian',   'May'),
    ('Freddie', 'Mercury'),
    ('John',    'Deacon'),
    ('Roger',   'Taylor')
;
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT Surname,
       NULL AS SurnameInitial,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY Surname
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS Surname,
       LEFT(Surname,1) AS SurnameInitial,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY LEFT(Surname,1)
```

**Query 1 Results**

```
+---------+----------------+-------+
| Surname | SurnameInitial | Count |
+---------+----------------+-------+
| Deacon  | NULL           |     1 |
| May     | NULL           |     1 |
| Mercury | NULL           |     1 |
| Taylor  | NULL           |     1 |
| NULL    | D              |     1 |
| NULL    | M              |     2 |
| NULL    | T              |     1 |
+---------+----------------+-------+
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT Surname,
       LEFT(Surname,1) AS SurnameInitial,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Surname ), (LEFT(Surname,1)) ) 
ORDER BY SurnameInitial, Surname
```

**Query 2 Results**

Despite the `ORDER BY SurnameInitial` and the fact that `NULL` sorts first in SQL Server the rows with `SurnameInitial` as `NULL` are ordered last.

```
+---------+----------------+-------+
| Surname | SurnameInitial | Count |
+---------+----------------+-------+
| Deacon  | D              |     1 |
| May     | M              |     1 |
| Mercury | M              |     1 |
| Taylor  | T              |     1 |
| NULL    | NULL           |     1 |
| NULL    | NULL           |     2 |
| NULL    | NULL           |     1 |
+---------+----------------+-------+
```

Query 1 and 2 *should* return the same results. The problem is that SQL Server decides to treat it like the following SQL

```
WITH GrpSets AS
(
SELECT Surname,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY Surname
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS Surname,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY LEFT(Surname,1)
)
SELECT Surname,
       LEFT(Surname,1) AS SurnameInitial,
       Count
FROM GrpSets
```

This just looks like a bug to me (trace flag 8605 shows that the damage is already done in the initial query tree representation). [BUG REPORT](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40432948-grouping-sets-returns-incorrect-results).

**Query 3**

```
SELECT Surname,
       LEFT(FirstName,1) AS FirstNameInitial,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Surname ), (LEFT(FirstName,1)) )
```

**Query 3 Results**

```
+---------+------------------+-------+
| Surname | FirstNameInitial | Count |
+---------+------------------+-------+
| NULL    | B                |     1 |
| NULL    | F                |     1 |
| NULL    | J                |     1 |
| NULL    | R                |     1 |
| Deacon  | NULL             |     1 |
| May     | NULL             |     1 |
| Mercury | NULL             |     1 |
| Taylor  | NULL             |     1 |
+---------+------------------+-------+
```

Query3 does not meet the problematic pattern of grouping on a column and an expression referencing that column. It wouldn't even be possible for the same issue to occur here anyway because the grouping sets part is equivalent to

```
SELECT Surname,
       NULL AS FirstNameInitial,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY Surname
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS Surname,
       LEFT(FirstName,1) AS FirstNameInitial,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY LEFT(FirstName,1)
```

This does not pass out the entire `FirstName` column upstream (or even have a guaranteed unique  `FirstName` column that *could* be passed out) so it isn't possible for the `LEFT(FirstName,1)` expression to be calculated on top of that.

For the same reason you don't see the issue with `(RN10), (SUBSTRING(RN,3,99))`.

[@i-one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/99746/i-one) reasons in the comments that it is likely

> a bug in normalization (algebrization). It has logic that finds a
>   match for non-aggregated columns and expressions in the `SELECT` list
>   within members of `GROUP BY`. The same logic seemingly allows us to
>   write for example
>
> ```
> SELECT Surname, LEFT(Surname, 1), COUNT(*)
> FROM   Queen
> GROUP BY Surname
> ```

without having to explicitly add the calculated expression as below

```
GROUP BY Surname, LEFT(Surname, 1)
```

Or another example would be

```
SELECT Surname,
       LEFT(Surname,1) AS SurnameInitial,
       LEFT(Surname,2) AS SurnamePrefix,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM   Queen
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Surname ), (LEFT(Surname,1)) )
```

In this case the `LEFT(Surname,2)` is allowed and the only way of computing it would be to do it in the manner that is problematic for the `LEFT(Surname,1)` case.